# Property 'on' does not exist on type 'EthereumProvider'

Tags: javascript, events, ethereum, metamask

I'm trying to basically use the window.ethereum provider to interact with Metamask but can't set event listeners just as mentioned in the Metamask doc.
I'm literally just doing this in a TypeScript class constructor :
`window.ethereum?.on('accountsChanged', this.handleAccountChange);`

The window.ethereum provider seems ok for most of the stuff but I get that error (the title) in VSCode.

In the console when I log window.ethereum I indeed can't seen some 'on' stuff :

```
{_events: {…}, _eventsCount: 0, _maxListeners: 100, _log: u, _state: {…}, …}
chainId
: 
"0x89"
enable
: 
ƒ ()
id
: 
"MetaMask"
isMetaMask
: 
true
networkVersion
: 
"137"
request
: 
ƒ ()
selectedAddress
: 
"0xf2dd55f59256bd65f41d2517c27a8b5fa780a18b"
send
: 
ƒ ()
sendAsync
: 
ƒ ()
_events
: 
{}
_eventsCount
: 
0
_handleAccountsChanged
: 
ƒ ()
_handleChainChanged
: 
ƒ ()
_handleConnect
: 
ƒ ()
_handleDisconnect
: 
ƒ ()
_handleStreamDisconnect
: 
ƒ ()
_handleUnlockStateChanged
: 
ƒ ()
_jsonRpcConnection
: 
{events: o, stream: d, middleware: ƒ}
_log
: 
u {name: undefined, levels: {…}, methodFactory: ƒ, getLevel: ƒ, setLevel: ƒ, …}
_maxListeners
: 
100
_metamask
: 
Proxy {isUnlocked: ƒ, requestBatch: ƒ}
_rpcEngine
: 
s {_events: {…}, _eventsCount: 0, _maxListeners: undefined, _middleware: Array(4)}
_rpcRequest
: 
ƒ ()
_sendSync
: 
ƒ ()
_sentWarnings
: 
{enable: false, experimentalMethods: false, send: false, events: {…}}
_state
: 
accounts
: 
['0xf2dd55f59256bd65f41d2517c27a8b5fa780a18b']
initialized
: 
true
isConnected
: 
true
isPermanentlyDisconnected
: 
false
isUnlocked
: 
true
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
_warnOfDeprecation
: 
ƒ ()
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
```

Any idea ? I'm lost for now...

Answer (score 0):

your app is not connected to the metamask. Click on metamask extension and you should see this pop up

[image]

you have to manually connect

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have other ethereum extension active (I deactivated XDefi). I have other wallets active but none for EVM chains. Moreover, in the "window.ethereum" dump I pasted, isMetamask is true. I really can't figure out what's going on...

Comment: your app is not connected.

Comment: I was connected but since the window.ethereum was a proxy object, I store its value and too early, before the real connection. My bad but at least you showed me the way ! Thanks